# AWS Lambda Function(Python) and Issues with External packages: Cyptodome.Hash

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

So I have a test python lambda function that calls a simple method that relies on the py-algorand-sdk. This is my first time working with AWS Lambda, but my code has worked for a while now running locally in docker containers. I found with aws lambda function, to get my packages in my requirements.txt, I need to actually pull them and zip them up, then passing them as a lambda layer so that my lambda function will be able to use those external packages. BUT when I run my test function, something in the py-algorand-sdk is calling Cryptodome and that is causing an error I just can not get passed.

### requirements.txt

```
requests==2.28.1
py-algorand-sdk==1.20.1
multihash==0.1.1
py-cid==0.3.0
pycryptodomex==3.16.0
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20221210.0

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./mycode  /mycode 

# Prepare amazonlinux image
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" && \
    yum -y install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel wget build-essential python3-dev

# Get and unpack Python 3.9
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    tar zxvf Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.9.7/ && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make altinstall && \
    cd .. && \
    rm Python-3.9.7.tgz

# Pull the requirements and install
RUN python3.9 -m venv /requirements && \
    /requirements/bin/pip3.9 install --upgrade pip && \
    /requirements/bin/pip3.9 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt -t ./python

# Copy in our code as module and zip
RUN cp -rf /mycode  ./python/ && \
    zip -r python_layer.zip ./python/
```

At this point I copy up the zip file into aws as a layer and test my lambda function... but for days I keep getting the same error, even after trying everything I could find online.

```
Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Hash._SHA512': Not found '_SHA512.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'...
```

I have tried using pycrypto, pycryptodome, pycryptodomex; I have tried removing the target flag and installing everything directly in the venv and copying all the site-packages into a zip. Nothing seems to work, so I must be missing something.

Any help would save me from pulling out any more hair.

### Full Error

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Hash._SHA512': Not found '_SHA512.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', Cannot load '_SHA512.abi3.so': /opt/python/Cryptodome/Util/../Hash/_SHA512.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Not found '_SHA512.so'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    from mycode import *\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/mycode/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from . import transactions\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/mycode/transactions.py\", line 5, in <module>\n    from algosdk.v2client import algod\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/algosdk/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from . import abi\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/algosdk/abi/__init__.py\", line 6, in <module>\n    from algosdk.abi.address_type import AddressType\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/algosdk/abi/address_type.py\", line 8, in <module>\n    from algosdk import encoding\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/algosdk/encoding.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA512\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/Cryptodome/Hash/SHA512.py\", line 29, in <module>\n    _raw_sha512_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib(\"Cryptodome.Hash._SHA512\",\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/Cryptodome/Util/_raw_api.py\", line 309, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib\n    raise OSError(\"Cannot load native module '%s': %s\" % (name, \", \".join(attempts)))\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Based strictly on the error message, it looks the OS (amazonlinux:2.0.20221210.0) does not include that module and not in the repository. I would standup and EC2 with amazonlinux:2.0.20221210.0 and installing the python application to recreate the error.  Alternatively, download the module and included in the application zip file.

Comment: So I have spun up the docker container defined above, removed the -t argument so that the requirements were installed directly to the venv, and executed the code. Nothing complains, everything works fine. Thats what is driving me nuts.

Comment: Not saying that this will fix the issue, but once the 'venv' environment has been created, it it needs to be activated, (just doting the Is & crossing Ts). Maybe it's done automatically or i don't see it.

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate the input! So as far as i understand it for pulling the packages, using `requirements/bin/python3.9 install -r requirement.txt -t {target}` will pull the needed packages into a target dir without the need to activate the env. I def could be wrong with that but I have also tested those packages in the docker container manually after having this issues. Where I just hopped into the docker container and executed the commands, and others, after activating the venv and ran tests there, and zipping manually and but sill no success to get around this error.

Comment: See this answer, maybe not exactly the same, but may provide some ideas as to cause, https://github.com/CastagnaIT/plugin.video.netflix/issues/1234  -  t-morales commented on Oct 1, 2021.